# Why rand() every time I refresh the page?

Tags: php, random

I want to run mini program for confirmation security question :

```
$questions = array('dog legs','car legs','the best country in the world');
$answers = array(4,4,'USA');
$questionId = rand(0, (count($questions)-1));
```

and then

```
$ans = $_POST['answer'];
if($ans == $answers[$questionId]){echo 'Confirmed !';}
```

So the prob is that not every time that I answer the answer is correct, because after sending form the rand function runs and changes the question ! Any solutions ?

Comment: You send a new request when you refresh and the script is re-run... That's the expected behavior.

Comment: Mmm, subjective security questions.

Comment: You can add the question ID to the post or use a session to store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to know what the original question was as well. Easiest way to do that would be just to post the question in the form as a hidden input :

```
<form>
    <?php echo $questionID; ?>
    <input type="text" name="answer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo $questionID; ?>" />
</form>
```

and do

```
$questions  = array('dog legs','car legs','the best country in the world');
$answers    = array(4,4,'USA');
$questionID = rand(0, (count($questions)-1));

if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    $answer   = $_POST['answer'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];

    if ( $questions[ $question ] == $answer ) // you're golden
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass in the form an hidden input with as value the question ID, that way the id will be resent.

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $questionId; ?>"></input>
```

Then check if the form is submitted.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['questionID'])
    $questionID = $_POST['questionID'];
else
    $questionID = rand(0, (count($questions)-1));
```

You can also secure all this by using base64 encoding

Comment: Editing the hidden field, users could "decide" which question ID they want. We shouldn't store the question id on the client side

Comment: @DanielAranda - How would that be a security risk, either you know the answer or you don't, the question is already posted on the page anyway ?

Comment: @adeneo in this case is not a security risk. Thought only that session could be better because we do not share the question id. But sharing question id in this use case, does not generate any risk as you said. Just I always as best practice try to never store "server side" values in the client due possibles manipulations.

Comment: @DanielAranda - this is one of those cases where it does'nt really make sense to store it in the session, as it's not really session data, it's just an already known value that's used to compare against the answers, which are safely kept on the serverside.

Comment: You're right @DanielAranda , indeed the user could do that but as adeneo said this is not a security risk. Moreover I think the user could also edit your session value if he really wanted right? And with the base64 encoding, which could also be replaced by any other "obfuscation" algorithm by the way, we can say that this option is pretty safe after all.

Comment: @ValHook - There's no need to encrypt this in any way, the question is already posted on the page, and changing the question that is sent to the server makes no difference, as the answer will be just as wrong anyway. This is done all the time, echoing values to data attributes and hidden form fields, and for data that is not needed for the entire session this is the way to do it.

Comment: @H2CO3 you do not know how the things move on. The cookie used for the session vars is the PHPSID but the value of the sessions vars are on the server.

Comment: @DanielAranda And can't that be retrieved using a request to the server? It surely can...

Comment: @DanielAranda Damn thanks I didn't know sessions value were server sided, thanks a lot for telling me that :)

Comment: @H2CO3 you do not understand the point. Let's think that you are user from "mywebsite.com" and I want to store a session var for you containing "he is from stackoverflow". As it is stored in the server you will never know that I flag you as "he is from stackoverflow"

Comment: @ValHook no problem. It is tricky a lot of people things that session vars are stored in the "cookie" of the session. But not, in the cookie is stored only a PHPSID that PHP uses for retrieve the sessions vars when PHP Script is being executed. If you want to store something in a cookie you should use $_COOKIE['value']

Answer (score 4):

### Best way:

Basicly you need to save the question id into the users session.

### Workaround:

If thats to complicated, do the following.

Create a secret string.
Create md5 from secret string + correct answer.
Write the md5 into a form hidden field.
On form submission, check if the secret string + given answer returns the md5 from the form.

Unless someone knows your secret string, you are safe even without sessions.

### Attention

My workaround has the same problem than storing the question ID into the form like sugegsten in another answer: One could simply manipulate the question ID to always show a once-solved question. Session is the only more or less safe way

Best regards

Zsolt